# Best practice to render a dynamic list of checkboxes depending on ViewModel entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So currently i am facing a problem where i really stuck since i am not that experienced in MVC. I am implementing the permission module for our web application. For that i have a Viewmodel which is called "SourceAccessViewModel" and it looks like this.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Weytec.Wdp.Config.Grpc;
    using Weytec.Wdp.Data.Contracts;
    
    namespace Weytec.Wdp.Config.Web
    {
        public class SourceAccessViewModel
        {

        public Guid? DeviceId { get; set; }
        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
        public bool? HasAccess { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public bool? MouseOnly { get; set; }
        public bool IsNew { get; set; } = false;
        public SourceAccessLevelPEnum AccessRight { get; set; }

        public List<EndpointAccessViewModel> EndpointAccessRights { get; set; }

        public SourceAccessViewModel()
        {

        }

        public SourceAccessViewModel(InheritedSourceAccessRight entity)
        {
            DeviceId = entity.DeviceId;
            Device = entity.Device;
            DeviceName = entity.Device.Name;
            DisplayName = entity.DisplayName.Value;
            ProfileId = entity.ProfileId;
            MouseOnly = entity.MouseOnly.Value;
            EndpointAccessRights = entity.EndpointAccessRights.Values.Select(x => new EndpointAccessViewModel(x)).ToList();
            AccessRight = entity.AccessRight.Value;
        }


        public SourceAccessViewModel(SourceAccessRight entity)
        {
            DeviceId = entity.DeviceId;
            Device = entity.Device;
            ProfileId = entity.ProfileId;
            DisplayName = entity.DisplayName;
            DeviceName = entity.Device?.Name;
            MouseOnly = entity.MouseOnly;
            EndpointAccessRights = entity.EndpointAccessRights.Select(x => new EndpointAccessViewModel(x)).ToList();
            AccessRight = entity.AccessRight;
        }
    }
}

In this ViewModel there is a List of Viewmodels which are related to the endpoint access rights of the device.

It looks like this:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Weytec.Wdp.Config.Grpc;
    using Weytec.Wdp.Data.Contracts;
    
    namespace Weytec.Wdp.Config.Web
    {
        public class EndpointAccessViewModel
        {
            public string EndpointName { get; set; }
            public Guid EndpointId { get; set; }
            public bool? HasAccess { get; set; }
    
            public EndpointAccessViewModel()
            {
    
            }
    
            public EndpointAccessViewModel(InheritedSourceAccessRight.InheritedEndpointAccessRight entity)
            {
            EndpointName = entity.Endpoint.Name;
            EndpointId = entity.EndpointId;
            HasAccess = entity.HasAccess.Value;
        }

        public EndpointAccessViewModel(EndpointAccessRight entity)
        {
            EndpointName = entity.Endpoint.Name;
            EndpointId = entity.EndpointId;
            HasAccess = entity.HasAccess.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see there is a list of EndpointAccessRightsViewmodels in there which looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Weytec.Wdp.Config.Grpc;
using Weytec.Wdp.Data.Contracts;

namespace Weytec.Wdp.Config.Web
{
    public class EndpointAccessViewModel
    {
        public string EndpointName { get; set; }
        public Guid EndpointId { get; set; }
        public bool? HasAccess { get; set; }

        public EndpointAccessViewModel()
        {

        }

        public EndpointAccessViewModel(InheritedSourceAccessRight.InheritedEndpointAccessRight entity)
        {
            EndpointName = entity.Endpoint.Name;
            EndpointId = entity.EndpointId;
            HasAccess = entity.HasAccess.Value;
        }

        public EndpointAccessViewModel(EndpointAccessRight entity)
        {
            EndpointName = entity.Endpoint.Name;
            EndpointId = entity.EndpointId;
            HasAccess = entity.HasAccess.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now my problem**. In the view i render the edit template like for the DeviceAccessRights like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditAccessRights", "User", new { deviceId = Model.DeviceId, profileId = profileId }, FormMethod.Post, true, null))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeviceId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsNew)
    <div>
        <div class="marginTop30px rowOfEntry">
            <div>Description:</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "textbox", required = "Required" })</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowOfEntry">
            <div>Access right:</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccessRight, Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(Weytec.Wdp.Config.Grpc.SourceAccessLevelPEnum)), new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowOfEntry">
            <div>Mouse Only:</div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MouseOnly, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="marginTop20px">
        <input type="submit" onclick="fadeIn()" class="btn btn-success saveButtonPopup" value="Save" />
        <asp:Label id="savedForm" style="color: #0FB335" runat="server">Source access right saved</asp:Label>
    </div>

}
```

After that i want to render the same thing for the Endpoint accesses but the clue is that it's not always filled. Its only filled in the Sourceaccessright Viewmodel if there is a access right being set for the endpoint. But i want to render the Checkbox anyway for this case, just not checked. So at the moment i am just rendering the Endpoints of the correspond device with a checkbox but its not related to the SourceAccessRightViewModel.

```
    @foreach (var endpoint in Model.Device.Endpoints)
    {

<div class="marginTop25px">
    <h5>Endpoint access right: @endpoint.Name</h5>

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.EndpointAccessRights[i].HasAccess, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = endpoint.Id } })
</div>
    }
```

Maybe an option would be to parse the viewmodel via JSON so with an ajax request but that sounds not like the best solution.
I really don't know how i can solve this at the moment.. can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of problem and solved it in this way.

You get all EndpointAccessRight (the different types) and compare it with the collection of EndpointAccessRight for 1 InheritedSourceAccessRight. If the type is not in the collection then add it to the collection and set it to false or null. Now you have an entire collection of EndpointAccessRight that contains all types and the view will be uniform.

**Example (might not be 100% correct)**

```
foreach (var endpointAccessRight in allEndpointAccessRights)
        {
            if (!inheritedSourceAccessRight.EndPointAccessRights.Any(item => item.EndpointId == endpointAccessRight.EndpointId ))
            {
                endpointAccessRight.HasAccess = false; // or null
                inheritedSourceAccessRight.EndPointAccessRights.Add(endpointAccessRight);
            }
        }
```